# Masking phone number with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

My application has a specific phone number format which looks like `999.111.222`, which I have a regex pattern to mask it on front-end:

```js
/[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.([0-9]{3})/
```

But recently, the format was changed to allow the middle three digits to have one less digit, so now both `999.11.222` and `999.111.222` match. How can I change my regex accordingly?

```js
"999.111.222".replace(/[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.([0-9]{3})/, '<div>xxx.xxx.$1</div>')
```

**expected output:**

```
"999.111.222" // xxx.xxx.222
"999.11.222" // xxx.xx.222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
console.log(
  "999.11.222".replace(/[0-9]{3}\.([0-9]{2,3})\.([0-9]{3})/, function ($0, $1, $2)
  { return '<div>xxx.' + $1.replace(/\d/g, 'x') + '.' + $2 + '</div>'; })
)
```

The `([0-9]{2,3})` first capturing group will match 2 or 3 digits, and in the callback method used as the replacement argument, all the digits from th first group are replaced with `x`.

You may further customize the pattern for the first set of digits, too.

Answer (score 5):

Replace {3} with {2,3} to match two or three digits.

```
/[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{2,3}\.([0-9]{3})/
```

For reference see e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-quantifier-range)

Comment: That will not help OP, since the second part (between dots) needs to be masked with `x`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you should change not only your regex but also your callback replace function:

```js
const regex = /[0-9]{3}\.([0-9]{2,3})\.([0-9]{3})/;
const cbFn = (all, g1, g2) =>`<div>xxx.xx${(g1.length === 3 ? 'x' : '')}.${g2}</div>`;

const a = "999.11.222".replace(regex, cbFn);
const b = "999.111.222".replace(regex, cbFn);

console.log(a, b);
```

To change regex you could add a term with `{2,3}` quantifier, as already suggested, and create a new group. Then, in replace cb function, you can use length to know if you must put a new `x`.